# Cannot parse JSON response

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am trying to parse my JSON response so I can print a specific value. Please help me in the right direction.

I am getting the following response:

```
{
  "services": [{
    "id": "9999999",
    "domainname": "example.com",
    "total": "100.90",
    "status": "Active",
    "billingcycle": "Monthly",
    "date": "2017-11-25",
    "category": "mobile phone",
    "url": "example.com",
    "name": "Iphone"
  }]
}
```

How can I be able to print only the "name" value of this JSON value?

**What I tried:**

```
$someData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
// this print the whole response
print_r($someData);

foreach($someData['services'] as $result) {
    echo $result['name'], '<br>';
}
```

But the `foreach` loop does not print the value which I need from the JSON response. What's wrong with this piece of PHP code?

**Update: edited the json the first name was domainname my bad**

Comment: Good question. Maybe because you have two fields named "name"?

Comment: By the way: it's best to use the data types representing the actual data, so `"9999999"` should be `9999999` and `"100.90"` should be `100.90`.

Comment: @Randall sorry my bad during changing some data

Comment: Your code appears to be working. I suggest that you check exactly what is in the real JSON you're working with. This example is clean as far as I can see.

Comment: @LSerni this is the exact ouwput only the names are changed. This php code is running as wordpress plugin

Comment: Then, the problem cannot be that *PHP does not print* - because it *does* print. The problem is that you do not *see* what it prints. Have you tried outputting something else (e.g. "Hello world" in a DIV with size 72 points) or looking for the output in the HTML source?

Comment: @Noob your code and json work as is for me (copy-paste) in one of my testing harnesses. Make certain you posted the `json` exactly as the one that is failing.

Comment: Are you able to control the JSON input? The confusing part might be that you have an array of `services` (indicated by the `[..]` brackets, which requires you to use the foreach in your sample).
After the `json_decode(..)` a `print $someData['services'][0]['name'];` does print the value (explicit access of the first array element here).

Comment: @zefixlluja i did not know that this was working i wil try this. Thx

Comment: @LSerni its a admin plugin with one php file to get a api reponse from my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple syntax error here

```
echo $result['name'],'<br>';
```

Try this

```
echo $result['name']. '<br>';
```

with a `.` dot instead of a comma `,`

Otherwise It works fine as you can see here.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9be6789973b0e70772403a786b379749f6db0a7a

I suggest turning error reporting on.

```
 <?php
      error_reporting(-1);
      ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And you will be able to see most of these issues more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your help i will test this tomorrow morning. Where will this error reporting be logged since its a wordpress admin plugin.

Comment: it will be output  on the screen, so turn it off when your done coding it.

Comment: A comma instead of a dot, in this case, will do the same thing. There will be no php error nor notice about it, and the echo will show both the variable contents and `<br>` after.

Comment: @Randall - who knew, then I don't see any problems.  So the JSON data must not be what the `OP` thinks it is, that is the only solution.

Comment: Yeah, something isn't adding up right somewhere. The example code seems fine.

Comment: Tested right now and its working maybe syntax error dunno but helps is appreciated